# Incomplete Google Search Result URL during Web-Scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, search, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape some Linkedin profiles via python. Many of the results that i get are incomplete (as shown in the image).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBFyn.png)

As you can see, there are profiles ending with "...". Is there any way to get complete profile links like others in the screenshot? Or is there any way where i can skip the incomplete profiles and get only the ones with complete links?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to aid you. We cannot help without code. What have you tried? SO is not here to do the coding for you, but we are very willing to help solve a specific coding problem.

Comment: are you sure those are incomplete and not just the truncated form? If you share your code, we can help you. Otherwise, you're not going to get much of a response.

Comment: The code is of no use here. Code simply fetches the result from google search result. i have manually seen the google web page results and the results displayed on google are of the form as shown in the screenshot.